# expiring php redirect on set date

Tags: php, date, redirect

I.m looking for a way in Php to have a Redirect expire on a said day.

The use for this is that I'm sharing file on a sever using the code below.
What I like is to have that redirect take them to a page that lets them know there time is up and they can see the Redirect anymore or tell I update the date of expire.

```
   if (test){
---do something---
die("<script>location.href = 'http://file.here.com'</script>");
} else {
   return false;
}
```

I have also try

```
function BeforeProcessList(&$conn, &$pageObject)
{
$target_date = new DateTime("05-01-2014");
 $today = new DateTime();
if((int)$target_date->diff($today)->format('%r%a') >= 0)
{
 header("Location: testview_list.php");
 exit();
}
}
```

Comment: are you redirecting in the php side? why don't want to use `header("Location: http://file.here.com");
die();` ?

Comment: AWA to be fare with you my knowledge of Php is about 16H of cutting code apart to find how it work. so noob

Comment: Im doing it on Php as there is no date base. I was just trying to find a way to hide the Redirect. i was just del the php from the server when i remember. and im sick of remembering lol

Comment: here's the pseudo code. First `let php process if the time is up `, if the time is up `echo your time is up.. redirecting`.. then use javascript setTimeout to redirect on the page , then `end`

Answer (score 0):

> There are several scenarios for this case but i suggest to use session.

Use additional session to be taken once your privilege period is valid and make sure that you've already insert a date when a user get into that file along with value that indicate this user is allowed , for example,1 so you can change a value to ,for example,0 after specific period and that user will be denied automatically or redirected to another page

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

```
<?php
// has this expired?
$expire_date = "2015-08-25"; // good until Aug 8/15
$now = date("Y-m-d");
if ($now>$expire_date) {
header("Location: http://yoursite.com/outoftime.html");
die();
}
// and now the unexpired part of the page ...

header("Location: http://yoursite.com/fileshare/");
die();
```

Thanks for the help guys